# Способы описания размещения компонентов

Tags: android, java

Я смотрю, тут многие пишут под андроид. А как лучше писать UI: в XML или в java-коде? Или без разницы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML - рекомендация лучших собаководов.

Этим обеспечивается разделение UI и кода, да и пишется проще, на мой взгляд. Еще один плюс: в Eclipse можно сразу посмотреть результат, без запуска на устройстве.

Comment: Я понимаю, что так можно задать только простой UI. Т.е. если у меня компоненты добавляются в цикле из списка каких-либо значений, например, то в XML уже не задать. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Так можно описать интерфейс любой сложности. Если компоненты добавляются в цикле, тогда, конечно, лучше программно. Однако, в этом случае может подойти ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Можно в xml описывать компоненты, а в коде настраивать их свойства.
А можно вообще все сделать в коде, но это не наглядно.
А еще можно накидать МНОГО компонетов в xml  в состоянии visible==GONE, а из кода включать те, которые нужны.